# React JS: data flow between grandparents/grandchildren

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I intend to set up the following React Component

```
    <tab-box>
        <title>Example</title>
        <butons>
            <button id="actionID1"></button>
            <button id="actionID2"></button>
            <button id="actionID3"></button>
        </butons>
        <content>
            <tabList>
                <tab id="tab1" label="label1"></tab>
                <tab id="tab2" label="label2"></tab>
            </tabList>
        </content>
    </tab-box>
```

Where I would like to pull out each `label` attribute for `tab` to set up a nav bar on top of the actual content.

The question is, how do I pull out the attributes from nested children? Or how can I restructure the component so that I don't have this issue?

Thought1: use a global Store service, children like `tab` populate the Store and parents may retrieve them when being mounted

UPDATE, Thought2: make `labels` a prop on tab-box, but I still don't feel quite right..

Comment: Have you looked at Refs? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html. You could technically get the array that populates the tabList children and iterate over their props.

Comment: I have checked that, it might be my last resort if nothing else comes up. I remember React's Doc mentioning specifically not to rely too much on refs.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. So will tabList always contain the same tabs or is it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it, but i doubt it is what you ultimately want. You want the parent to obtain information about the child? This doesn't make sense as you are trying to create "components" and not some code specific to one task.

Think of it this way. The tabs should be using tab component to display its own information. Under what circumstance would the tab know more than its parent? If so then is it even a component? Who is using who?

React is suited for one way data flows from parent to child, so it makes more sense to hold information in tabs component, and pass pieces of info to child tabs.

```
<tabs>
    <button text={tab[0].text}/>
    <tab>
        write transcluded children here
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

Even this begs the question - why are you using so many components to begin with? Why not use css classes to represent tabs container and individual tabs like a normal person?

If you insist on making a tabs component, at least keep it all in one component, something like

```
<tabs data={[{title:"tab-title", content: (<p>stuff</p>)}]} />
```

Also I absolutely do not agree with defining tabs in a model/store. common sense is UI and data should be separate.

As someone else mentioned you can use ref, but i'd reserve that for very limited purposes such as getting a field from a form.

Comment: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-tabs I found this library which does similar things as me, I might like to investigate before I set an answer